# zsh-git-prompt customization of path

Tags: zsh, prompt

```
source ~/zsh-git-prompt/zshrc.sh
PROMPT='%B%m%~%b$(git_super_status) %# '
```

I have the default configuration for [zsh-git-prompt](https://github.com/olivierverdier/zsh-git-prompt) as shown above

In my prompt it outputs:

```
cmuench-air /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phppos/PHP-Point-Of-Sale(master|✔) %
```

I would like it to look like this instead:

```
cmuench-air PHP-Point-Of-Sale(master|✔) %
```

How do I change configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` sequences used in the prompt are documented in the `zshmisc` man page under *SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES*.

`%~` expands to the path and the manual elaborates under `%/` (because `%~` is "as `%d` and `%/`"):

> If an integer follows the `%', it specifies a number of trailing  components  of
>                 the current working directory to show; zero means the whole path.  A negative integer specifies leading com‐
>                 ponents, i.e. %-1d specifies the first component.

So, the short answer to your question is: **Replace `%~` in your prompt with `%1~`**.